# How to change the color of an image using CSS3?

Tags: css

I want to change the color of an image from grey to green/red/yellow with CSS3. I had tried with below code but it's not working.

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: blue(100%);
    filter: blue(100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently [CSS `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) supports following filters functions,

```
/* <filter-function> values */
filter: blur(5px);
filter: brightness(0.4);
filter: contrast(200%);
filter: drop-shadow(16px 16px 20px blue);
filter: grayscale(50%);
filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
filter: invert(75%);
filter: opacity(25%);
filter: saturate(30%);
filter: sepia(60%);

/* URL to SVG filter */
filter: url("filters.svg#filter-id");
```

You may have to try with `filter: url()` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

A number of possible solutions to achieve this.

**A**: Using [CSS Blend Modes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode). There's a pretty straight-forward guide on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/) about them. For the colour green, you'd simply do:

```
.image-green {
  background-image: url(image.jpg);
  background-color: green;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

And repeat that for your other colours of choice. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/andreasvirkus/Lxwsxcgj/)

**B**: If you're fixed on the idea of using `filter`, then you'll need to use `filter: hue-rotate` to achieve that. It takes a degree value like this:

```
.blue {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andreasvirkus/agvkj7dd/)

**C**: This is more of an overlay, but it works great for grayscale images. You can set a pseudo-element overlay and colour it any colour you'd like with a simple `background-color` attribute! Check out an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/andreasvirkus/agvkj7dd/1/)

```
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(50, 200, 50, 0.4);
}
```

Comment: Great! Happy to help. If this works for you, you can mark it as the correct answer to help others as well in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one feature currently added to the modern browsers to change the color of the image i.e. `filter (-web-filter for chrome and safari)`. But the main issue is that as you have enquired in your question about changing color but i guess it only applies as a filter as the name suggests. It is currently supported by all modern browsers so we can use this feature on fly.It can help you in many situations and can be alternative to many ui designs and to understand this more clearly you can check out this codepen link. 
https://codepen.io/Deep_Purple/pen/gGXvMR